# Zipping same value over a list of tuples Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

I would like to transform the following tuple list

```
a = [(1,()),(2,())]
```

into a nested tuple list by the same value

```
b = [(False,(1,())),(False,(2,()))]
```

Using the zip function in this format

```
zip [False] a
```

only gives me

```
[(False,(1,()))]
```

Any suggestions or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why use `zip` when you have `map`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you zip two lists of different lengths, you get the length of the shortest list.

You can fix this by zipping against an *infinitely long* list:

```
zip (repeat False) a
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, instead of using `zip` you can use `map`:

```
map (\x -> (False, x)) a
```

This would more appropriately express your intent (in my opinion) since you want to do the same thing to every element of the list.  If you want to do different things to each element, then `zip` or `zipWith` may be more appropriate.

If you wanted to avoid the lambda, you can write it pointfree using `&&&` from `Control.Arrow`:

```
map (const False &&& id) a
```

which basically says "apply the functions `const False` and `id` to the input, then construct a tuple of both of their outputs".  There is the `TupleSections` extension which would allow you to write this as

```
map (False,) a
```

(tip provided by [@thoferon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458734/zipping-same-value-over-a-list-of-tuples-haskell/30459344#comment49003251_30459344)), but I personally find this less clear, since you have to know that the extension is enabled and notice the `,` after `False`.  You could write it as

```
map ((,) False) a
```

without the extension since `(,)` acts as a function of type `a -> b -> (a, b)`, and while a bit more verbose it doesn't require enabling a language extension.

Comment: Or with TupleSections: `map (False,) a`

Comment: @thoferon Certainly, but in this case I would honestly say that it would make it less clear.  The difference between `map (False,) a` and `map (False) a` is only 1 character, and that character is very important.  I would rather have `map (const False &&& id)` using `Control.Arrow` if I were going for pointfree.  It doesn't require extensions and is very clear code (provided you know what `&&&` does).  Considering this requires an import and several more characters, I don't mind a pointful lambda for this simple case.

Comment: Using an arrow here and not thoferon's version is just plain silly. Your last suggestion (in prefix notation) is also good.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I would disagree. I happen to like arrow syntax quite a bit, and particularly when working with lots of tuples they come in handy. In both cases you have to type extra, but I often find myself already having `Control.Arrow` imported.  For those trying to keep Haskell98, the arrow approach would be more desirable.  I prefer to keep `(False,)` as a syntax error (just as `[False,]` is) and instead reach for solutions that don't require changing the language.  At the end of the day it's really just a matter of personal style.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to others answers it is also possible to write a generic function for any `Functor`, not just for lists:

```
strengthL :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f (a, b)
strengthL = fmap . (,)

strengthR :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f (b, a)
strengthR = fmap . flip (,)
```

Then `strengthL` can be applied to False and the original list:

```
Prelude> strengthL False [(1,()),(2,())]
[(False,(1,())),(False,(2,()))]
```